# calculating upper and lower quartiles

Tags: statistics, soft-question, descriptive-statistics

The number of goals scored by a football team during a months worth of matches is recorderd.

They scored $0$ goals $4$ times, $1$ goal $6$ six times and $2$ goals $3$ times. Calculate the lower and upper quartiles.

Would it simply be this?:  lower quartile is the $3.5$th value which is zero, and upper quartile is the $10.5$th value which is $2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have data on 4 + 6 + 3 = 13 games. $13 \cdot 0.25 = 3.25$, and $13 \cdot 0.75 = 9.75$. We round these to $3$ and $10$, respectively. We line up all our values in order:
$$ 0\; 0\; 0\; 0\; 1\; 1\; 1\; 1\; 1\; 1\; 2\; 2\; 2 $$

The third value is $0$. the 10th value is $1$.

Comment: but I've seen the formula for LQ as (n+1)/4, not n/4

Comment: @user108605 "For discrete distributions, there is no universal agreement on selecting the quartile values." That is to say that there are many ways of taking quartiles, and nobody's really sure which way is "right". Use whatever particular method you use in class. There are several decent methods. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile

Comment: ok thanks I think I will stick with my formula. Its fits better with the median formula (n+1)/2